# Match everything between but exclude words - notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Input:

```
start
some
T1
random
T2
text
T3
end
```

should result in:

```
start
T1
T2
T3
end
```

I tried using

```
>(?<=start)[\S\s]*?(?=end)
```

to match everything between start and end

and exclude T1 T2 T3 with:

`^(?!T\d)`

Is it possible to combine them into a single regex that can be pasted into notepad++ for people not familiar with writing code to do it in several passes?

Comment: No, that is not possible in one go. It is easier to do with a PythonScript. Also, a regex can be written, but several *Replace All* hits will be required for it to remove all unnecessary `Tn` lines and then a regex to grab the `start\K(?s:.*?)(?=end)` can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regular expression:

**Find:** `^(?!T\d|start).*\R(?=(^(?!start$).*\R)*end$)`
       **Replace:** (empty)
       **`.` matches newlines:** No

Click "Replace All"

These assumptions are made:

- The `start` and `end` delimiters should each be the only text on their lines (so not `---start` or `start ///`),
- They should appear in pairs in the correct order (so first `start` and then `end`)
- They should not be nested, so after a `start` cannot come another `start` before you have an `end`.

The look-ahead makes this a rather inefficient regular expression, as with each match it needs to check again the text that follows until the next `end`.

Comment: Thank you, also for pointing out the limits. There is one problem though, that everything in the text file is matched as soon as there are more than 50 lines before the 'start' delimiter. That's even when every 50 lines are the same.

Comment: I tried again and the limit is not 50, but 191. I tried by adding 191 lines of "TEST" before the delimiter start. Why is that?

Comment: That looks like a limitation in Notepad++, as there is absolutely no reason for this in the regular expression itself. I suppose the look-ahead is aborted after a certain number of lines and/or characters, which should not be done.